# Setting File read pointer at the beginning

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

Consider the following code below in which for each  entry in key.txt I  add it to each line in plain.txt and write it to the output.txt.

```
 Dim srKeyFile As New StreamReader("D:\Test\key.txt")

        Dim srOutFile As New StreamWriter("D:\TestBial\output.txt")
        Dim strKey, strPlain As String
        While srKeyFile.Peek() >= 0
            Dim srPlainFile As New StreamReader("D:\TestB\plain.txt")
            strKey = srKeyFile.ReadLine()
            Dim key As Integer = Integer.Parse(strKey)
            While srPlainFile.Peek() >= 0
                strPlain = srPlainFile.ReadLine()
                Dim plain As Integer = Integer.Parse(strPlain)
                srOutFile.WriteLine("" + (key + plain).ToString())
            End While
            srPlainFile.Close()
        End While
        srOutFile.Close()
```

Above I have to open and close the inner file on each iteration of the outer loop.Is there some way That I could position my pointer to beginning,each time I enter the inner loop for the file plain.txt

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use StreamReader's BaseStream.Seek to do this, but you need to call [DiscardBufferedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.discardbuffereddata.aspx) first:

```
    srPlainFile.DiscardBufferedData()
    srPlainFile.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
```

Comment: why there is need of discardBuffer method?

Comment: I'm not completely sure it's necessary, but it might be. Here's some info:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.discardbuffereddata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx